# Visual Studio pops to the foreground without reason

Tags: visual-studio

I am experiencing this weird problem with Visual Studio 2022.
I created the skeleton of a new web application using individual accounts.
I have run the first migration, created some default accounts in the aspnet identity tables and
finally launched the application to test if everything was correctly setup in my PC.

Visual Studio compiles the application without problems and launch the defaul browser (Edge).
The standard Welcome page appears but immediately Visual Studio pops to the front doing nothing.
No errors, no messages nothing wrong. Just the code window here to obscure the browser window.
Now, I switch to the browser window and click on the Login link.
Again, the login window briefly appears in the browser but it is immediately obscured by Visual Studio.
Switch again to the browser, compile the required fields and click on login.
Again Visual Studio thinks that he is the best app on the planet and brings itself on the foregroud.

I have tried to switch to another browser, but the results are the same.
I have tried with an existing application written with Visual Studio 2019, but again the "pop in front of everything" still happens.
I have tried to search for this problem but probably I haven't find the right keywords to represent this problem correctly to a search engine.

I think that probably I have something wrong in the Visual Studio configuration, but it is practically impossible to find something there if you don't know what to look for.
The only option that seems to be related is "Bring Visual Studio to the foreqround when breaking in the debugger" but even after uncheking the option the "pop to front" persists.

So my question is simple. Has anyone experienced a similar behavior? If yes how have you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, probably this situation is so messed that none will ever see this post.
Nevertheless I would like to share how I have finally resolved the question and leave here a warning for future readers.

The cause of Visual Studio 2022 hiccups is, probably, the import of Visual Studio 2019 settings.
I thought that it was a good idea to set 2022 with the same options used in the last 3 years so, after installing VS 2022
I used this very useful menu (*Tools->Import Export Settings*) to export all the Visual Studio 2019 Settings in an XML file and I reimported it in 2022.

I thought, if the file is not compatible with VS2022 surely it will abort the import. Right?
No, Visual Studio 2022 doesn't complain during the import of 2019 settings.
But something in that exported file should be very broken.

I have resolved the problem with these steps

- Close Visual Studio 2022
- Open a command prompt window with administrator rights
- Change to the install folder for Visual Studio 2022 and then change dir to subfolder "Common7\IDE"

Finally execute the command

```
devenv /ResetSettings
```

After this everything started to work as expected without problems.
I have saved the broken VS2019 setting file and tried to compare it with one produced after the reset,
but they have too many differences to extract something useful to identify the specific problem area